# can't get latlng from react useref

Tags: react-leaflet

Recently, I just started utilizing leftlet in my React ts project. I want to implement a draggable marker on the map. However, I cannot do anything with the return ref.

```
  const [position, setPosition] = React.useState(TEMP.center);
  const markerRef = React.useRef(null);

  const eventHandlers = React.useMemo(
    () => ({
      dragend() {
        const marker = markerRef.current;
        if (marker != null) {
          setPosition(marker.getLatLng());
        }
      },
    }),
    []
  );
```

and I get this error

```
Property 'getLatLng' does not exist on type 'never'.  TS2339

    50 |         const marker = markerRef.current;
    51 |         if (marker != null) {
  > 52 |           setPosition(marker.getLatLng());
       |                              ^
    53 |         }
    54 |       },
    55 |     }),
```

Comment: This is a typescript error because you don't add a type to your `useRef`. `const markerRef = useRef<{ getLatLng(): string; }>(null);`. Try something like that - where the return type of the generic type fits your scenario. Update the question/answer with the result please :-)

Answer (score 1):

Change line 2 to:

```
    const markerRef = useRef<any>(null)
```

I ran into the same issue, this fixed it for me. Thanks to jnelson for the tip.